# toggle function works but not slideToggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make the `slideToggle` work but couldn't figure out. As per different answers, I tried adding `display: block` and `display: none` but that isn't working either.

JSFiddle Demo: **https://jsfiddle.net/987cndtv/**

JS:

```
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent ul").hide();
jQuery(".menupolicies>li>ul").show();
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent > span").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
  /* jQuery(this).next("ul").toggle(); */
});
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent .nav-header").click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).find("img").toggleClass( "arrow" );
});
```

CSS:

```
.menupolicies .parent {
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: block;
}
.menupolicies .parent ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the version (*3.3.1.slim.min.js*) of jQuery you are using which does not have the animation effect required in `slideToggle()`. Try with some other version:

```js
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent ul").hide();
jQuery(".menupolicies>li>ul").show();
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent > span").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
  //jQuery(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
});
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent .nav-header").click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).find("img").toggleClass( "arrow" );
});
```

```css
.hide {
 display: none;
}
.menupolicies>li {
  width: 100%;
}
.menupolicies .parent {
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: block;
}
.menupolicies .parent ul {
  display: none;
}
.menupolicies a, .menupolicies li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
.menupolicies .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav {
 margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menupolicies .parent span img {
  width: 24px;
  float: right;
}
.menupolicies .arrow {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moduletable">
  <ul class="nav menupolicies">
    <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header hide">Market</span>
    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
      <li class="deeper parent"><a href="/market/terms">Terms 1</a></li>
      <li class="current active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 2</span></span>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
          <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa">Terms A</a></li>
          <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header "><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png" alt="Fleet"><span class="image-title">Terms B</span></span>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
              <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsb/i">Terms I</a></li>
              <li class="current active"><a href="/market/terms/termsa/ii">Terms II</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa/iii">Terms III</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 3</span></span>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
          <li class=""><a href="/market/terms3/i">Terms I</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```